# Splitting a sentence by ending characters

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

A recent project has me needing to split incoming phrases (as strings) into their component sentences. For instance, this string:

`"Your mother was a hamster, and your father smelt of elderberries! Now go away, or I shall taunt you a second time. You know what, never mind. This entire sentence is far too silly. Wouldn't you agree? I think it is."`

Would need to be turned into a list composed of the following elements:

```
["Your mother was a hamster, and your father smelt of elderberries",
"Now go away, or I shall taunt you a second time",
"You know what, never mind",
"This entire sentence is far too silly",
"Wouldn't you agree",
"I think it is"]
```

For the purposes of this function, a "sentence" is a string terminated by `!`, `?`, or `.` Note that punctuation should be removed from the output as shown above.

I've got a working version, but it's quite ugly, leaves leading and trailing spaces, and I can't help but think there's a better way:

```
from functools import reduce

def split_sentences(st):
  if type(st) is not str:
    raise TypeError("Cannot split non-strings")
  sl = st.split('.')
  sl = [s.split('?') for s in sl]
  sl = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, sl) #Flatten the list
  sl = [s.split('!') for s in sl]
  return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, sl)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `re.split` instead to specify a regular expression matching any sentence-ending character (and any following whitespace).

```
def split_sentences(st):
    sentences = re.split(r'[.?!]\s*', st)
    if sentences[-1]:
        return sentences
    else:
        return sentences[:-1]
```

Comment: Nice. It may help the OP if you explained the if-else.

Comment: If there's a terminator at the end of the input string, the `re.split` will return an array with an empty item at the end. Empty strings are falsy, so if the last item of the array [-1] is empty, return a range of everything but the last item.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without regexes:

```
result = [s.strip() for s in String.replace('!', '.').replace('?', '.').split('.')]
```

Or, you could've written a bleeding-edge algorithm that doesn't copy data around so much:

```
String = list(String)

for i in range(len(String)):
    if (String[i] == '?') or (String[i] == '!'):
        String[i] = '.'

String = [s.strip() for s in String.split('.')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

st1 = "  Another example!! Let me contribute 0.50 cents here?? \
         How about pointer '.' character inside the sentence? \
         Uni Mechanical Pencil Kurutoga, Blue, 0.3mm (M310121P.33). \
         Maybe there could be a multipoint delimeter?.. Just maybe...  "

st2 = "One word"

def split_sentences(st):
    st = st.strip() + '. '
    sentences = re.split(r'[.?!][.?!\s]+', st)
    return sentences[:-1]

print(split_sentences(st1))
print(split_sentences(st2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `split` to split them at specific special characters.

```
import re
str = "Your mother was a hamster, and your father smelt of elderberries! Now go away, or I shall taunt you a second time. You know what, never mind. This entire sentence is far too silly. Wouldn't you agree? I think it is."
re.compile(r'[?.!]\s+').split(str)
```