# extracting n-grams from tweets in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

Say that I have 100 tweets.
In those tweets, I need to extract: 1) food names, and 2) beverage names.

**Example of tweet:**

> "Yesterday I had a coca cola, and a hot dog for lunch, and some bana split for desert. I liked the coke, but the banana in the banana split dessert was ripe"

I have to my disposal two lexicons. One with food names, and one with beverage names.

Example in food names lexicon:
"hot dog"
"banana"
"banana split"

Example in beverage names lexicon:
"coke"
"cola"
"coca cola"

**What I should be able to extract:**

> [[["coca cola", "beverage"], ["hot dog", "food"], ["banana split", "food"]],
>   [["coke", "beverage"], ["banana", "food"], ["banana split", "food"]]]

The names in the lexicons can be 1-5 word(s) long. How do I go about extracting n-grams from the tweets, using my lexicons?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you have tried so far, below is a solution using `ngrams` in `nltk` and `dict()`

```
from nltk import ngrams

tweet = "Yesterday I had a coca cola, and a hot dog for lunch, and some bana split for desert. I liked the coke, but the banana in the banana split dessert was ripe"

# Your lexicons
lexicon_food = ["hot dog", "banana", "banana split"]
lexicon_beverage = ["coke", "cola", "coca cola"]
lexicon_dict = {x: [x, 'Food'] for x in lexicon_food}
lexicon_dict.update({x: [x, 'Beverage'] for x in lexicon_beverage})

# Function to extract lexicon items
def extract(g, lex):
    if ' '.join(g) in lex.keys():
        return lex.get(' '.join(g))
    elif g[0] in lex.keys():
        return lex.get(g[0])
    else:
        pass

# Your task
out = [[extract(g, lexicon_dict) for g in ngrams(sentence.split(), 2) if extract(g, lexicon_dict)] 
        for sentence in tweet.replace(',', '').lower().split('.')]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[['coca cola', 'Beverage'], ['cola', 'Beverage'], ['hot dog', 'Food']], 
 [['coke', 'Beverage'], ['banana', 'Food'], ['banana split', 'Food']]]
```

---

**Approach 2** (Avoid "coca cola" and "cola")

```
def extract2(sentence, lex):
    extracted_words = []
    words = sentence.split()
    i = 0
    while i < len(words):
        if ' '.join(words[i:i+2]) in lex.keys():
            extracted_words.append(lex.get(' '.join(words[i:i+2])))
            i += 2
        elif words[i] in lex.keys():
            extracted_words.append(lex.get(words[i]))
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return extracted_words

out = [extract2(s, lexicon_dict) for s in tweet.replace(',', '').lower().split('.')]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[['coca cola', 'Beverage'], ['hot dog', 'Food']], 
 [['coke', 'Beverage'], ['banana', 'Food'], ['banana split', 'Food']]]
```

Noted that `nltk` is not needed here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I do like that solution, but the problem is that when a bigram is successfully extracted, then there should not be a unigram extracted from the same part of text as well.

Example:
"I love coca cola" should only be able to generate "coca cola". Not "coca cola" and "cola". The only solution to this that I can think of is to delete that part and re-run the left-over, but then I lose the context of the original sentence, which is also important. Is there a better way?

Comment: @AnonX I have edited my answer. How about the 2nd approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple solution:

```
import re

def lexicon_by_word(lexicons):
    return {word:key for key in lexicons.keys() for word in lexicons[key]}



def split_sentences(st):
    sentences = re.split(r'[.?!]\s*', st)
    if sentences[-1]:
        return sentences
    else:
        return sentences[:-1]

def ngrams_finder(lexicons, text):
    lexicons_by_word = lexicon_by_word(lexicons)
    def pattern(lexicons):
        pattern = "|".join(lexicons_by_word.keys())
        pattern = re.compile(pattern)
        return pattern
    pattern = pattern(lexicons) 
    ngrams = []
    for sentence in split_sentences(text):
        try:
            ngram = []
            for result in pattern.findall(sentence):
                ngram.append([result, lexicons_by_word[result]])
            ngrams.append(ngram)
        except IndexError: #if re.findall does not find anything
            continue
    return ngrams

# You could customize it
text = "Yesterday I had a coca cola, and a hot dog for lunch, and some bana split for desert. I liked the coke, but the banana in the banana split dessert was ripe"

lexicons = {
    "food":["hot dog",
             "banana",
             "banana split"],

    "beverage":["coke",
                 "cola",
                 "coca cola"],
     }
print(ngrams_finder(lexicons, text))
```

split_sentences function taken from here: [Splitting a sentence by ending characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593428/splitting-a-sentence-by-ending-characters/43596240)

Comment: BTW, have you seen this feature? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663870/find-multi-word-terms-in-a-tokenized-text-in-python

Comment: Thanks @artona, the regexp-solution seems to be the best so far, but do you think there's any way of doing this with POS-tagged words in a list? I'm thinking of doing nltk.pos_tag(), but then I won't be able to pass whole sentences into the pattern-finder

Comment: @alvas Thank u for showing me that I will change solution after asking few questions to AnonX

Comment: @AnonX Do you want to preserve pos-tagged words in a list after finding patterns? Please show me the input and requested output of such action in your post.

Comment: @artona Thank you for your reply. I have posted an updated version of this to answer your questions best I can. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091931/n-grams-from-text-in-python). - Please let me know in that post if more clarification is needed. Thank you for your help! :)