# n-grams from text in python

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, n-gram

An update to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064114/extracting-n-grams-from-tweets-in-python), with some changes:


Say that I have 100 tweets.
In those tweets, I need to extract: 1) food names, and 2) beverage names. I also need to attach type (drink or food) and an id-number (each item has a unique id) for each extraction.


I already have a lexicon with names, type and id-number:

```
lexicon = {
'dr pepper': {'type': 'drink', 'id': 'd_123'},
'coca cola': {'type': 'drink', 'id': 'd_234'},
'cola': {'type': 'drink', 'id': 'd_345'},
'banana': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_456'},
'banana split': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_567'},
'cream': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_678'},
'ice cream': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_789'}}
```

Tweet example:

After various processing of "tweet_1" I have this sentences:

```
sentences = [
'dr pepper is better than coca cola and suits banana split with ice cream', 
'coca cola and banana is not a good combo']
```

My requested output (can be other *type* than *list*):

```
["tweet_id_1",
 [[["dr pepper"], ["drink", "d_124"]],
  [["coca cola"], ["drink", "d_234"]],
  [["banana split"], ["food", "f_567"]],
  [["ice cream"], ["food", "f_789"]]],

 "tweet_id_1",,
 [[["coca cola"], ["drink", "d_234"]],
  [["banana"], ["food", "f_456"]]]]
```

It's important that the output should **NOT** extract unigrams within ngrams (n>1):

```
["tweet_id_1",
 [[["dr pepper"], ["drink", "d_124"]],
  [["coca cola"], ["drink", "d_234"]],
  [["cola"], ["drink", "d_345"]],
  [["banana split"], ["food", "f_567"]],
  [["banana"], ["food", "f_456"]],
  [["ice cream"], ["food", "f_789"]],
  [["cream"], ["food", "f_678"]]],

 "tweet_id_1",
 [[["coca cola"], ["drink", "d_234"]],
  [["cola"], ["drink", "d_345"]],
  [["banana"], ["food", "f_456"]]]]
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to run my sentences in various nltk filters like lemmatize() and pos_tag() **BEFORE** the extraction to get an output like the following. But with this regexp solution, if I do that, then all the words are split into unigrams, or they will generate 1 unigram and 1 bigram from the string "coca cola", which would generate the output that I did not want to have (as the example above).
The ideal output (again the *type* of the output is not important):

```
["tweet_id_1",
 [[[("dr pepper", "NN")], ["drink", "d_124"]],
  [[("coca cola", "NN")], ["drink", "d_234"]],
  [[("banana split", "NN")], ["food", "f_567"]],
  [[("ice cream", "NN")], ["food", "f_789"]]],

 "tweet_id_1",
 [[[("coca cola", "NN")], ["drink", "d_234"]],
  [[("banana", "NN")], ["food", "f_456"]]]]
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064114/extracting-n-grams-from-tweets-in-python ?

Comment: Not duplicate, but very similar

Answer (score 4):

May not be the most efficient solution, but this will definitely get you started -

```
sentences = [
'dr pepper is better than coca cola and suits banana split with ice cream', 
'coca cola and banana is not a good combo']

lexicon = {
'dr pepper': {'type': 'drink', 'id': 'd_123'},
'coca cola': {'type': 'drink', 'id': 'd_234'},
'cola': {'type': 'drink', 'id': 'd_345'},
'banana': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_456'},
'banana split': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_567'},
'cream': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_678'},
'ice cream': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_789'}}

lexicon_list = list(lexicon.keys())
lexicon_list.sort(key = lambda s: len(s.split()), reverse=True)

chunks = []

for sentence in sentences:
    for lex in lexicon_list:
        if lex in sentence:
                chunks.append({lex: list(lexicon[lex].values()) })
                sentence = sentence.replace(lex, '')

print(chunks)
```

**Output**

```
[{'dr pepper': ['drink', 'd_123']}, {'coca cola': ['drink', 'd_234']}, {'banana split': ['food', 'f_567']}, {'ice cream': ['food', 'f_789']}, {'coca cola': ['drink', 'd_234']}, {'banana': ['food', 'f_456']}]
```

**Explanation**

`lexicon_list = list(lexicon.keys())` takes the list of phrases that need to be searched and sorts them by length (so that bigger chunks are found first)

The output is a list of `dict`, where each dict has `list` values.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot make comments due to my low reputation, but the answer of Vivek could be improved through 1) regex, 2) including pos_tag tokens as NN, 3) dictionary structure in which you could select tweets result by a tweet:

```
import re
import nltk
from collections import OrderedDict

tweets = {"tweet_1": ['dr pepper is better than coca cola and suits banana split with ice cream', 'coca cola and banana is not a good combo']}

lexicon = {
'dr pepper': {'type': 'drink', 'id': 'd_123'},
'coca cola': {'type': 'drink', 'id': 'd_234'},
'cola': {'type': 'drink', 'id': 'd_345'},
'banana': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_456'},
'banana split': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_567'},
'cream': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_678'},
'ice cream': {'type': 'food', 'id': 'f_789'}}

lexicon_list = list(lexicon.keys())
lexicon_list.sort(key = lambda s: len(s.split()), reverse=True)

#regex will be much more faster than "in" operator
pattern = "(" + "|".join(lexicon_list) +  ")"
pattern = re.compile(pattern)

# Here we make the dictionary of our phrases and their tagged equivalents
lexicon_pos_tag = {word:nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(word)) for word in lexicon_list}
# if you will train model that it recognizes e.g. "banana split" as ("banana split", "NN")
# not as ("banana", "NN") and ("split", "NN") you could use the following
# lexicon_pos_tag = {word:nltk.pos_tag(word) for word in lexicon_list}

#chunks will register the tweets as the keywords
chunks = OrderedDict()
for tweet in tweets:
    chunks[tweet] = []
    for sentence in tweets[tweet]:
        temp = OrderedDict()
        for word in pattern.findall(sentence):
            temp[word] = [lexicon_pos_tag[word], [lexicon[word]["type"], lexicon[word]["id"]]]
        chunks[tweet].append((temp))
```

Finally Output is:

```
OrderedDict([('tweet_1',
          [OrderedDict([('dr pepper',
                         [[('dr', 'NN'), ('pepper', 'NN')],
                          ['drink', 'd_123']]),
                        ('coca cola',
                         [[('coca', 'NN'), ('cola', 'NN')],
                          ['drink', 'd_234']]),
                        ('banana split',
                         [[('banana', 'NN'), ('split', 'NN')],
                          ['food', 'f_567']]),
                        ('ice cream',
                         [[('ice', 'NN'), ('cream', 'NN')],
                          ['food', 'f_789']])]),
           OrderedDict([('coca cola',
                         [[('coca', 'NN'), ('cola', 'NN')],
                          ['drink', 'd_234']]),
                        ('banana',
                         [[('banana', 'NN')], ['food', 'f_456']])])])])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the point of pos_tag is not to say that every "banana" should be NN, but instead find only those bananas that are of type NN in the pre-trained model.

Comment: Sure, but as I have indicated in the comment  above lexicon_pos_tag... if you will execute the above code after training pos_tag model, the code: 
`lexicon_pos_tag = {word:nltk.pos_tag(word) for word in lexicon_list}`
will create a dictionary like 
{"banana split": ("banana split", "NN")}. 

Then it will be utilized further in the code `temp[word] = [lexicon_pos_tag[word],...` properly.

Comment: Thank you! Currently, I'm working on your original regexp solution. But I'll give the updated a go too! Very good inputs! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would a for loop to filter ..

Use if statements to find the string in the keys.. if you wish to include unigrams, delete

`len(key.split()) > 1`

If you wish to only include unigrams then change it to:

`len(key.split()) == 1`

```
 filtered_list = ['tweet_id_1']

 for k, v in lexicon.items():
     for s in sentences:
         if k in s and len(k.split()) > 1:
             filtered_list.extend((k, v))

  print(filtered_list)
```

Comment: This wouldn't find "banana" in the second sentence. It should be about to detect all ngrams, but not generate duplicates of same string.